# Docker Toolbox port mapping not working

Tags: docker, port, docker-toolbox, linux-containers

I have installed docker toolbox on a windows machine, after running a container with the following  command, I didn't see anything listening on my host machine's specified port (82).

```
docker run -ti -p 82:80 --name=container_alias someprovider/image:some_tag
```

I did attach to this contianer and did a simple check **inside the container** using:

```
curl localhost:80
```

it did return html source content, which means the container is running properly.
What could be the reason of this unexpected behavior?

Comment: What's the output of `docker-machine ip`? Docker won't be listening on `localhost` as your using Docker toolbox which uses Virtualbox and it's networking. Only Docker for Windows can listen on `localhost` because it uses Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have another server set-up on localhost but I can't be sure. Docker Machine doesn't map to localhost. Unless you've somehow set-up localhost to redirect to the IP address of your docker machine.

You may want to read [Get started with Docker Machine and a local VM](https://docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/)
.

Also `-p 82:80` exposes the container's port 80 to the machine's port 82. So you would need to `curl someipaddress:82`

Comment: to be clear I was inside the container, so I curled against port 80. on the host machine it's just connection refused on port 82.

Comment: Ah ok sorry misread that. In the container, what ip address are you running on? If you set it to 0.0.0.0 does that fix it?